# django - How to create app equivalent to "admin"?

Tags: django

I have recently started learning Python & Django. I have gone through the Django tutorial twice now and am beginning to feel comfortable with its contents.

My goal is to make an app pretty much like the Django "Admin" site. What I am unsure about is how to go about it in the most efficient way.

Based on what I have learned from the tutorials I have had a go at making my app and am successfully displaying readonly data.

What I would like to do now is give users the ability to modify the data themselves, create new records etc etc, pretty much exactly the same way that the "admin" site works. Is there a shortcut way of implementing this, versus coding it all myself?

As the "admin" interface was built automatically to suit my model, i figure it should be possible to do something similar for the user facing side of the app without having to recode it all?

Any help greatly appreciated!

cheers
James (python & django newbie)

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what your site is for? I ask because, if it's relatively low-traffic or serving a known, closed userbase (an intranet for example), there's nothing wrong with setting up appropriate permissions using admin users and groups and just letting your users access the admin.

Comment: Yep, its for a low serving, internal website. However, I am using this project to both learn python/django and build the required app. I'd prefer to build this "properly" and be able to build upon it over the years (improving this app and building others). Do i take it that its not possible to automatically generate the admin interface in the "user" side of the app then? Using or modding the admin interface would be the only "quick" option?

Comment: There's nothing improper about letting users into the admin if you control the permissions properly. [Mezzanine's demo](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) lets you do just that. If you want to provide a really customised control for letting users edit content then it's time to learn about [forms](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) (see also [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs)), which is where the fun of web development really starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. To summarise them:

1. No, there is not a quick way to generate something similar to "admin" in the user side of an app.
2. You can extend/mod the "admin" side to your requirements, and give users access to this area (customise the permissions for this).